# How to match multiple arrays?

Tags: php

I have multiple nested arrays:

```
array(
    [0]=>array('ID'=>123 ,'VALUE'=>value)
    [1]=>array('ID'=>124 ,'VALUE'=>value)
    )


array(
    [0]=>array('ID'=>123 ,'NAME'=>value)
    [1]=>array('ID'=>124 ,'NAME'=>value)
    [2]=>array('ID'=>125 ,'NAME'=>value)
    )
```

I have to find a match, for instance:

`if(ID=123)` I should get the ID, value, and name.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where you'll be wanting to use PHP's built in [multidimensional array features](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

```
$outputArray = array(); // Create an output array.

foreach ($array as $innerArray) // Assuming $array is an example of one of your arrays above.
// Iterate through each inner array in list and load it temporarily into $innerArray.
{
    if ($innerArray['ID'] == 123) // Your condition, checking for the value of key 'ID'.
    {
        $outputArray['ID'] = $innerArray['ID']; // The temporary inner array is loaded to the $outputArray variable.
        foreach ($innerArray as $name => $value) // Iterate through inner array.
        {
            if ($name !== 'ID') // If the key of the inner array is not 'ID' then handle this key => value pair.
            {
                $outputArray['Name'] = $name;
                $outputArray['Value'] = $value;
            }
        }
        break; // Break the loop if you know that there can be only 1 array with 'ID' => 123
    }
}

print_r($outputArray); // You can now access that particular array you wanted.
```

If you have multiple instances of arrays like in your example, you'll probably want to load all those arrays into yet another master array, and write yet another loop that wraps around this one.

The block of code I wrote handles one particular instance of your array examples.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

http://ideone.com/hiCRZ

```
$a = array(
    array('ID'=>123 ,'VALUE'=>'123 value'),
    array('ID'=>222 ,'VALUE'=>'222 value')
);

$b = array(
    array('ID'=>123 ,'NAME'=>'123 name'),
    array('ID'=>124 ,'NAME'=>'124 name'),
    array('ID'=>125 ,'NAME'=>'125 name')
);

$c = array();

foreach( $a as $row ){
  $c[ $row['ID'] ]['ID'] = $row['ID']; // stupid way to ensure target array :)
  $c[ $row['ID'] ] += $row;
}

foreach( $b as $row ){
  $c[ $row['ID'] ]['ID'] = $row['ID'];
  $c[ $row['ID'] ] += $row;
}

var_dump( $c );
```

Result:

```
array(4) {
  [123]=>
  array(3) {
    ["ID"]=>
    int(123)
    ["VALUE"]=>
    string(9) "123 value"
    ["NAME"]=>
    string(8) "123 name"
  }
  [222]=>
  array(2) {
    ["ID"]=>
    int(222)
    ["VALUE"]=>
    string(9) "222 value"
  }
  [124]=>
  array(2) {
    ["ID"]=>
    int(124)
    ["NAME"]=>
    string(8) "124 name"
  }
  [125]=>
  array(2) {
    ["ID"]=>
    int(125)
    ["NAME"]=>
    string(8) "125 name"
  }
}
```

If you want to find data for 1 id:

```
$id = 123;
$result_row = array();

foreach( $a as $row ) if( $row['ID'] == $id ) {
  $result_row += $row;
}

foreach( $b as $row ) if( $row['ID'] == $id ){
  $result_row += $row;
}

var_dump( $result_row );
```

Result:

```
array(3) {
  ["ID"]=>
  int(123)
  ["VALUE"]=>
  string(9) "123 value"
  ["NAME"]=>
  string(8) "123 name"
}
```